Calling SOAP API in NodeJs using certificate as authentication
I have this working PHP code, which goal is to call a SOAP service with SSL authentication:
<?php

$certificate = 'demo/certificate.pem';
$location = '<serverurl>';
$passphrase = '<passphrase>';
$wsdl = 'demo/Api.wsdl';

$soapClient = new SoapClient(
    $this->wsdl,
        [
            'local_cert'     => $this->certificate,
            'location'       => $this->location,
            'passphrase'     => $this->passphrase,
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
                'http' => ['user_agent' => 'PHP/SOAP'],
                'ssl'  => [
                    'verify_peer'      => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                ],
            ]),
        ]
);

// Check is a SOAP method defined in the WSDL
$result = $this->soapClient->Check([
    'checkReq' => [
        'operation' => 1,
        'voucherCode'  => 'abcd1234',
    ],
]);

print_r($result);

This works perfectly fine, and I get the response I expect from the SOAP call.
I am trying to do the same thing in NodeJS, using the node-soap library.
However, I am unable to correctly setup the SSL authentication.
I read the documentation and this article, and to me it looks like they are all referring to different types of certificate files from what I have.
I have only one single .pem file, which contains both the certificate and private key (exactly as the PHP SoapClient class expects).
However, by looking at the documentation of the ClientSSLSecurity and WSSecurityCert options, they both require two files.
I have tried splitting my .pem file in two (so that I have a "public" and "private" part) but I get an error, so I'm probably doing something wrong.
Here's my NodeJS code:
const https = require("https")
const fs = require("fs")
const axios = require("axios")
const soap = require("soap")

class ApiWrapper {
    async getClient() {
        const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./demo/private.pem', 'utf-8')
        const publicCertificate = fs.readFileSync('./demo/public.pem', 'utf-8')
        const password = '<passphrase>'

        const url = 'demo/Api.wsdl'

        const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
            key: privateKey,
            cert: publicCertificate
        })

        const wsdlRequest = await axios.create({
            httpsAgent
        })

        let client = await soap.createClientAsync(
            url,
            {
                request: wsdlRequest,
                wsdl_options: {
                    connection: 'keep-alive'
                }
            }
        )

        const wsSecurity = new soap.WSSecurityCert(
            privateKey,
            publicCertificate,
            password
        )

        client.setSecurity(wsSecurity)
        return client
    }
}

async function main() {
    const wrapper = new ApiWrapper()
    const client = await wrapper.getClient()
    const result = await client.CheckAsync()
    console.log({result})
}

main()


This gets me
Error: error:1C800064:Provider routines::bad decrypt
    at Sign.sign (node:internal/crypto/sig:128:29)
    at RSASHA1.getSignature (/<path_to_project>/node_modules/xml-crypto/lib/signed-xml.js:70:22)
    at SignedXml.calculateSignatureValue (/<path_to_project>/node_modules/xml-crypto/lib/signed-xml.js:453:32)
    at SignedXml.computeSignature (/<path_to_project>/node_modules/xml-crypto/lib/signed-xml.js:865:10)
    at WSSecurityCert.postProcess (/<path_to_project>/node_modules/soap/lib/security/WSSecurityCert.js:141:21)
    at Client._invoke (/<path_to_project>/node_modules/soap/lib/client.js:357:33)
    at /<path_to_project>/node_modules/soap/lib/client.js:187:18
    at /<path_to_project>/node_modules/soap/lib/client.js:165:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Client.CheckAsync (/<path_to_project>/node_modules/soap/lib/client.js:156:20) {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:11800074:PKCS12 routines::pkcs12 cipherfinal error',
    'error:1C800064:Provider routines::bad decrypt',
    'error:11800074:PKCS12 routines::pkcs12 cipherfinal error'
  ],
  library: 'Provider routines',
  reason: 'bad decrypt',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_BAD_DECRYPT'
}

What's the correct way of calling a SOAP service with SSL authentication with node-soap, when I have only one certificate file?

Can you post more of that stack trace please?  What line generates that error?

@MattMorgan I edited the question to include the full error message.

...This works perfectly fine... Yes, but you've disabled peer verification which means you're wide open to a MiTM attack.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I know but I kinda sorta don't care about that, because the PHP part is just a quick example I drafted just because I'm more familiar with that language than with Node. It was never meant to be put in production or anything like that, so I'm not concerned with any security issues.

Split your public certificate and private key with bash and disable SSL
Since you don't care about security I made a few changes and it's working. I think here is the way you're splitting the certificate and how you're not disabling SSL like you did with php.
Extract the private key with:
openssl rsa -in certificate.pem -out private.pem

Extract the public certificate with:
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -out public.pem 

Your code with some changes:
const https = require("https")
const fs = require("fs")
const axios = require("axios")
const soap = require("soap")

class ApiWrapper {
    async getClient() {
        const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./private.pem', 'utf-8')
        const publicCertificate = fs.readFileSync('./public.pem', 'utf-8')
        const password = '<passphrase>'

        const url = './Api.wsdl'

        const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
            key: privateKey,
            cert: publicCertificate,
            passphrase: password,
            rejectUnauthorized: false  //Will accept any certificate
        })

        const wsdlRequest = await axios.create({
            httpsAgent
        })

        let client = await soap.createClientAsync(
            url,
            {
                request: wsdlRequest, // axios instance
                wsdl_options: {
                    connection: 'keep-alive',
                    agent: httpsAgent,
                    strictSSL: false // Disable SSL verification
                }
            }
        )

        const wsSecurity = new soap.WSSecurityCert(
            privateKey,
            publicCertificate,
            password,
            'utf8' // proper encoding 
        )

        client.setSecurity(wsSecurity)
        return client
    }
}

async function main() {
    const wrapper = new ApiWrapper()
    const client = await wrapper.getClient()
    const result = await client.CheckAsync({
        checkReq: {
            operation: 1,
            voucherCode: 'abcd1234'
        }
    });
    console.log({result})
}

main()


I "don't care about security" in my PHP code because that's not meant to go to production or anything, it was just a quick example. But in the NodeJS code I definitely do care about security.

My changes will still work just change every false to true

it seems like the nodejs library of soap complaints for the decryption of the keys.
Did you try to pass keys as buffer??
Just change this
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./demo/private.pem', 'utf-8');
const publicCertificate = fs.readFileSync('./demo/public.pem', 'utf-8');

To this
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./demo/private.pem');
const publicCertificate = fs.readFileSync('./demo/public.pem);

